# Save and retrieve image from cookies using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to download images only one time whilst they are same. I need to save those images on network traffic.

How I can do this using AJAX Updates.

Thanks in advance 
Kuldeep Dwivedi

Answer (score 0):

set the expiration of you image.
It will be cached in the client browser.

**And saving image in cookies** :- You can't save any object in cookies. You can save only string in cookie.

Comment: But it does not mean that saving objects/arrays is impossible. He could just serialize/unserialize that.

Comment: serialization/de-serialization doesn't mean changing object to string or string to object .

Comment: He could store an object/array in a string, if that object/array was serialized. Then restore it back with unserialization.

Comment: [More detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)